# MS Access VBA Update Query to Clear All Check Boxes On a Form Not Working

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a button on my MS Access form that uses VBA to update the modified date/time stamp on all records on a datasheet style form that have a checkbox checked in a field called "Confirm Existing Update". After it makes these updates, it is supposed to clear all of the check boxes.  This is currently accomplished via a simple SQL update query that executes via VBA once the date/timestamps have been updated:

```
"Update [CMO Deviations Tracker] SET [CMO Deviations Tracker].[Confirm Existing Update] = FALSE WHERE [CMO Deviations Tracker].[Confirm Existing Update] = TRUE"
```

The problem is that the query doesn't seem to want to clear the last checkbox checked (in the last row that was interacted with).  I've tested the query by copy/pasting it into a blank query design window and it works perfectly there (clears all check boxes, including the final one clicked).  So far, I've attempted to add the following to my form button's VBA code:

- Shifting the record to the next line before running the Update query via "Me.Recordset.MoveNext"
- Saving the last record interacted with via "If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False"
- I added "Forms![CMO Deviations Tracker].Requery" to the end of the code to ensure that I was seeing the latest info

None of these seem to result in the clearing of the last checkbox checked.  What could be causing this?

EDIT: I just tried running my separate Update query while the form was open immediately after trying and failing with the button.  It failed to remove the last checkbox due to a "lock violation".  Interesting...

EDIT2: So the only thing that I've found to work (as a manual workaround) is to check the boxes for all of the rows that I want to update the timestamp for, and then check and uncheck the box for one additional row before clicking the button.  Access will then clear all of the desired check boxes like it's supposed to.

EDIT3: Just a point of clarity.  The updating of the timestamp on the last record checked appears to work perfectly.  It seems like, for whatever reason, it's only the "Confirm Existing Update" checkbox field that is getting locked.  Thinking that it could be the method being used, I attempted to clear these checkboxes by editing the Recordset and using a loop to make the "Confirm Existing Update" field for each of the rows in the Recordset equal to "False".  It still seems to clear all check boxes except the last one, only this time, the vba code will error out on the final line by saying "Could not update | currently locked".  Same error, completely different implementation.

EDIT4: Updating the "Record Locking" property of the form to either "Edited Record" or "No Locks" seems to fix the issue, but only if done as part of the button click code.  If I put VBA to update this property in the "On Open" event trigger of the form, or simply update the property in the GUI, it doesn't seem to fix the issue - even with "No Locks" set as the default property.  What the heck?

EDIT5:  Per request, the following is the VBA from my button.  Please note that I've updated the methodology to update the check boxes using a DAO.Recordset, rather than the original SQL Update query.

```vb
Private Sub Command187_Click()

Dim Temp_ID As String
Dim DBS_Temp1 As DAO.Database
Dim DevTracker As DAO.Recordset
Dim DevUpdates As DAO.Recordset


If MsgBox("This will confirm that the latest update provided is still current for all items with the 'Confirm Existing Update' box checked above.  Are you sure that you want to do this?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    Set DBS_Temp1 = CurrentDb
    Set DevTracker = DBS_Temp1.OpenRecordset("CMO Deviations Tracker")
    Set DevUpdates = DBS_Temp1.OpenRecordset("Deviation Updates")


    DevTracker.MoveFirst
    DevUpdates.MoveFirst

    Do Until DevTracker.EOF = True

    If DevTracker![Confirm Existing Update] = True Then

         DevUpdates.MoveFirst

         Temp_ID = "[Deviation ID] = '" & DevTracker![Deviation ID] & "'"

         DevUpdates.FindLast (Temp_ID)
         DevUpdates.Edit
         DevUpdates![Status Update] = DevUpdates![Status Update] & " "
         DevUpdates![Status Update] = Left(DevUpdates![Status Update], Len(DevUpdates![Status Update]) - 1)
         DevUpdates.Update

         DevTracker.Edit
         DevTracker![Confirm Existing Update] = False
         DevTracker.Update

    End If


    DevTracker.MoveNext


    Loop

    DevUpdates.Close
    DevTracker.Close

    Set DevUpdates = Nothing
    Set DevTracker = Nothing
    Set DBS_Temp1 = Nothing


    MsgBox "Existing updates for the selected deviations have been confirmed."


Else

    DevTracker.MoveFirst

    Do Until DevTracker.EOF = True

        DevTracker.Edit
        DevTracker![Confirm Existing Update] = False
        DevTracker.Update

        DevTracker.MoveNext

    Loop


    MsgBox "Update Confirmation Cancelled."

    Forms![CMO Deviations Tracker].Requery

    Exit Sub

End If

Forms![CMO Deviations Tracker].Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: *Saving the last record* should do it. Please add the relevant VBA code to your question.

Comment: Isn't that what "If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False" does? Regardless, I just tried to add DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord to the very beginning of my Button Click VBA code and the last record still appears to be locked.

Comment: Try throwing a form.refresh in there too.

Comment: Already done. It appears to based around the final record locking

Comment: I tested this. No errors and final record is updated. No requery needed. Post button code.

Comment: Per request, I've added the code from my button.  For context: the purpose of this code is to update the date/time stamp of the latest status note entered for any row that has a check box checked in the "Confirm Existing Update" column.  It does this by adding a space to the latest note and then deleting that space.  This aspect of the code works perfectly.  My interest is in understanding why the portion of the code that clears the check boxes isn't working.